# dexie's open method,neither secceed nor failed,y?

Tags: javascript, dexie

I'm using Dexie to store data in my frontend project,in a fortuitous situation，I found that the open function neither succeed nor failed.

```
const v = this.DBInstance.version(version)
        .stores(tables)
        .upgrade(trans => {
          console.log('更新数据库版本:', trans);
          // 更改现有库的索引
        });
      console.log('!!!!!!!!!', v);

      this.DBInstance.open()
        .then(res => {
          this.status = 'fullfilled';
          console.log('db open succeed!'); // won't be output in the console
        })
        .catch(err => {
          this.status = 'rejected';
          console.log('db open failed!'); // won't be output in the console
          console.error(err.stack || err);
        });
```

I open the chorme console's 'application' tab.there is nothing in the 'indexedDB' panel,including my database.so i guess maybe there are some problem happend in chrome.but I don't know how it came about，and I wonder why the promise which the open method returns will never fullfilled or rejected.
what's more, when I call the search method after those steps like this:

```
  queryAllFreshData = database
        .table('RESOURCE_FRESH')
        .where('projectId')
        .equals(projectId)
        .toArray();
  
  queryAllFreshData.then(res=>{
     // do sth
  }).catch(err=>{
    console.log(err)
  })
```

it's also won't fullfilled or rejected。

Answer (score 0):

Check if the database is blocked by another instance holding on to an earlier version. Can be detected using [db.on('blocked')](https://dexie.org/docs/Dexie/Dexie.on.blocked).

This can be prohibited by releasing connections when others try to upgrade. Dexie does this in its default implementation of [db.on('versionchange')](https://dexie.org/docs/Dexie/Dexie.on.versionchange) so you shouldn't need to override it though. Maybe the other connection was opened outside dexie, or is also a Dexie connection that overrides the versionshange event by returning `false`.

Comment: sry I didn't understand very much.It's seems not the problem with database versionChange or be blocked，first I didn't open any other window tabs of same tab so I think there won't be multi Dexie instance.I also tried subscribe the event 'blocked' and 'versionchange',it won't occurs;I also need't to upgrade the db version yet so I just comment the upgrade func。[my code]( https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-paper-xd7984?file=/src/dexie.ts)

Comment: This doesn't seem to be Dexie's problem，first all all，It only happens in few cases and I open a Non-trace mode browser，it works well。 when the problem appear ,I tried to open the database instead of native IDB in my code，I could see the result of IDBOpenDBRequest show ''Failed to read the 'result' property from 'IDBRequest': The request has not finished''.

Comment: If I understand your comments correctly, the problem does not appear when you open it in a "Non-trace mode browser". I assume you mean having devtools up. I'm thinking that maybe devtools is blocking your request from completing.